# How to detect key events of droplist while it is open

Tags: javascript, html

I can detect key events of a `<select>` element while it is closed, but when it is open I can't. Is there a way to do this using the native element?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5brstbn3/

Thanks!

Comment: you can set a size attribute on the select when focused to simulate the dropping down in a way that won't interrupt KB handling

Comment: @dandavis lol I had certainly not thought of that! It's a bit too hacky for me though.